# Clicking all elements with iMacros that contain specific string, but don't start with another specific string

Tags: imacros

Imagine you have a page with many clickable items - either "? items" (? can be any number, 4, 52, 355,…) or "Hide ? items". When you click "? items" list of subitems opens and "? items" is changed to "Hide ? items". And vice versa when you click "Hide ? items" list of subitems hides and "Hide ? items" is changed to "? items".

Now how to accomplish with iMacros that only items with name "? items" are clicked and not "Hide ? items"

You can click all "Hide ? items" and "? items" in loop with the following command:

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*<SP>items
```

Using wildcard (*) this matches all these items. Unfortunately REGEXP are not supported for TAG command. I want this command to click only "? items" elements, not "Hide ? items". Somehow exclude elements that begin with "Hide". Is this possible with iMacros and if how?

Answer (score 0):

So you may try this workaround:

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*<SP>items EXTRACT=TXT
SET curPos EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/Hide/) ? '' : {{!LOOP}};")
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS={{curPos}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*<SP>items
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```